# Evosuite test generation from command line on linux

Tags: evosuite

I am using Evosuite from the command line in Linux and I get an error.

the path for the project is: /home/ina/workspace/ina
the target class files are located in: /home/ina/workspace/ina/bin/paketa1

I use the command:
java -jar evosuite-0.2.0.jar -projectCP /home/ina/workspace/ina -target /home/ina/workspace/ina/bin/paketa1

Here is what I get:

- EvoSuite
- Found 2 matching classes in target /home/ina/workspace/ina/bin/paketa1
- Analyzing classpath (generating inheritance tree)

  - /home/ina/workspace/ina
  - /home/ina/workspace/ina/bin/paketa1
- Current class: Shembull2
- Going to generate test cases for class: Shembull2
- Starting client
- Connecting to master process on port 5601
- Analyzing classpath:
- Inheritance tree loaded from /tmp/ES_inheritancetree2503904095717002256.xml.gz
- Error while initializing target class: Target class not found in inheritance tree
  [MASTER] 14:01:22.015 [logback-2] ERROR TestSuiteGenerator - Problem for Shembull2. Full stack:
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Target class not found in inheritance tree
  at org.evosuite.setup.DependencyAnalysis.analyze(DependencyAnalysis.java:84) ~[evosuite-0.2.0.jar:na]
  at org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:221) ~[evosuite-0.2.0.jar:na]
  at org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:125) [evosuite-0.2.0.jar:na]
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_79]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
- Computation finished
  [MASTER] 14:01:22.162 [main] ERROR SearchStatistics - No statistics has been saved because EvoSuite failed to generate any test case
  [MASTER] 14:01:22.263 [main] ERROR TestGeneration - failed to write statistics data
- Current class: Shembull1
- Going to generate test cases for class: Shembull1
- Starting client
- Connecting to master process on port 14113
- Analyzing classpath:
- Inheritance tree loaded from /tmp/ES_inheritancetree2503904095717002256.xml.gz
- Error while initializing target class: Target class not found in inheritance tree
  [MASTER] 14:01:25.039 [logback-2] ERROR TestSuiteGenerator - Problem for Shembull1. Full stack:
  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Target class not found in inheritance tree
  at org.evosuite.setup.DependencyAnalysis.analyze(DependencyAnalysis.java:84) ~[evosuite-0.2.0.jar:na]
  at org.evosuite.TestSuiteGenerator.generateTestSuite(TestSuiteGenerator.java:221) ~[evosuite-0.2.0.jar:na]
  at org.evosuite.rmi.service.ClientNodeImpl$1.run(ClientNodeImpl.java:125) [evosuite-0.2.0.jar:na]
  at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_79]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) [na:1.7.0_79]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
- Computation finished
  [MASTER] 14:01:25.155 [main] ERROR SearchStatistics - No statistics has been saved because EvoSuite failed to generate any test case
  [MASTER] 14:01:25.256 [main] ERROR TestGeneration - failed to write statistics data

Any help would be very appreciated!
Thank You

Answer (score 1):

At a first look, it seems the classpath is not properly set. If you have a project in /home/ina/workspace/ina, and the .class files are compiled in the folder bin, then the classpath would be /home/ina/workspace/ina/bin

If you a class Foo in package "paketa1", like for example paketa1.Foo, then the classpath is still /home/ina/workspace/ina/bin, and not /home/ina/workspace/ina/bin/paketa1